# Non trivial Automorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that every finite group having more than two elements has a nontrivial Automorphism.

It is from Topics in Algebra by Herstein. I am not able to solve.

Comment: try $x\mapsto a^{-1}xa$.

Comment: Do you see how to solve this when some element has order $>2$?

Comment: @CutieKrait, great unless $G$ is abelian ... :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: then try $x\mapsto x^p$ for an appropriate $p$.

Comment: @CutieKrait, great unless every element of $G$ has order $2$ ... :)

Comment: @user1729: then solve the problem for $\Bbb Z_2^n$ for $n>1$.

Comment: @CutieKrait: indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is abelian with exponent greater than 2 (i.e. not every element has order 2). Then mapping $g\in G$ to $g^{-1}$ is an automorphism. It's clearly bijective, and since $G$ is abelian it is indeed a homomorphism.

If $G$ is abelian with exponent 2, then it is a vector space over $\mathbb Z/2$. Choose a basis for this vector space, and pick your favourite two basis vectors to interchange. This is a nontrivial automorphism.

If $G$ is not abelian, then the center of $G$, $Z(G)\neq G$. Now, let $G$ act on itself via conjugation. These are all automorphisms. Convince yourself that if $Z(G)\neq G$, there is a nontrivial one.