# Every finite group of order more than two has a nontrivial automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to prove that every finite group $G$ of order more than 2 has a nontrivial automorphism.  I've seen this question answered on this site for infinite groups, but the proofs given use the fact that if $g^2=1$ for every $g$ in $G$, then $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  This is an exercise in Herstein's text that appears before the section on (the fundamental theorem of) finite abelian groups.  I think I can prove this result using that theorem, but was wondering if there are more elementary proofs.

Here is my proof: If $G$ is nonabelian, then $\exists x \in G$ such that the map  $(T_x: g \mapsto x^{-1}gx)$ is a nontrivial automorphism of $G$.  So suppose $G$ is abelian.  Then the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$; this automorphism is nontrivial if some element in $G$ has order at least 3.  If every element in $G$ has order 2, then by the fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups, $G \cong C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$ is the direct product of $k$ copies of $C_2$ for some $k \ge 2$.  A map that interchanges the generators of the first two copies and fixes the remaining $k-2$ copies yields a nontrivial automorphism of $G$. QED.

Comment: This has been asked more than once before http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391453/non-trivial-automorphism

Comment: I think my question is not a duplicate because I am asking for a proof that does not appeal to the theorem on vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}/2$ or the fundamental theorem on finite abelian groups (which are used in the proofs given on this website so far).

Comment: The first paragraph of my question makes it clear I would like to see a proof (for finite groups) which does not use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups. So the proof referenced in the other webpage can't be used to answer my question.

Comment: The accepted answer on the other page does not use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Comment: @Jim The accepted answer on the other page does use the fact that if $G$ is abelian and has exponent 2, then $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  This fact is similar to the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Comment: The fact you're talking about is fairly trivial and it's "proof" is just routine checking that axioms hold.  I would hardly call that similar to a structure theorem for all finite abelian groups, but I guess it's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct, and with a slight adjustment applied to both finite and infinite groups:  In the last step you don't need the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.  An abelian group is a $\mathbb Z$-module.  If every element has order $2$ then it's a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-module, so a vector space, and the only vector space infinite or otherwise that doesn't have a nontrivial automorphism is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Why do you mention infinite groups? I see what you mean, later, but the problem is that, up front, it seems a little odd to bring it up - like a non sequitur.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are not yet covered at this point in the text.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: If you read the post the OP says he's seen this question answered for infinite groups.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that section, but you just repeat the proof that he references there, too.

Comment: lol, yea, I missed *that* section

Comment: The first paragraph of my question makes it clear I would like to see a proof (for finite groups) which does not use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.  So the proof referenced in the other webpage can't be used to answer my question.